# Как замокать метод .map интерфейса Page junit5?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

Метод `repositoryAuto.findAll(specification, pageable)` возвращает `Page<Auto>` и у меня получилось замокать эту часть  c помощью кода:

```
when(repositoryAuto.findAll(any(), (Pageable) any())).thenReturn(getAutoEntityPage());
```

Но в сервисе сам код выглядит так в одну строчку :

```
Page<AutoDTO> dtos = repository.findAll(specification, pageable).map(autoMapper::toShortDto);
```

Как можно замокать метод `.map` интерфейса `Page` ,чтобы он возращал `Page<AutoDTO>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
Page<Auto> getAutoEntityPage(Page<AutoDTO> dtoPage) {
  Page<Auto> autoPageMock = mock(Page.class);
  // не уверен, но возможно и .map(autoMapper::toShortDto) сработает, нужно проверить
  when(autoPageMock.map(any())).thenReturn(dtoPage); 
  
  return autoPageMock;
}


// передаем объект 
Page<AutoDTO> dtoPage = ...;
when(repositoryAuto.findAll(any(), (Pageable) any()))
   .thenReturn(getAutoEntityPage(dtoPage));
```